# ¿Como puedo insertar objetos desde un formulario con PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un formulario en el cuál quiero agregar mis resultados en un arreglo, lo que necesito es un arreglo multinivel para después mostrarlos en una tabla

```
<form action="#" method="POST">

        <label for="N1">Introduce un número: </label>
        <input type="number" name="n1" class="form-control" required>
        <input type="number" name="n2" class="form-control" required>
        <select name="operation" id="rst">
            <option value="multiplicar">Multiplicar</option>
            <option value="exponente">Exponente</option>
        </select>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Resultado" class="btn btn-primary">
 

        <?php

            $n1 = $_POST["n1"];
            $n2 = $_POST["n2"];
            $operation = $_POST["operation"];


            if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
                switch ($operation) {
                    case 'multiplicar':
                        $result = $n1 * $n2;
                        echo "La multiplicación de " .$n1. " * " .$n2. " es igual a " .$result;
                        break;
                    case 'exponente':
                        $result = $n1 ** $n2;
                        echo "El exponente de " .$n1. " sobre " .$n2. " es igual a " .$result;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        ?>

</form>
```

¿Cómo puedo agregar las variables $n1, $n2 y $resultado en un arreglo?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría separar tu código para tenerlo en dos archivos, ya que si lo ejecutas como está tendrías errores de indices inexistentes en $_POST en la primer llamada. Por ejemplo Archivo1.php y Archivo2.php

En el Archivo1.php puedes escribir:

```
<form action="Archivo2.php" method="POST">

    <label for="N1">Introduce un número: </label>
    <input type="number" name="n1" class="form-control" required>
    <input type="number" name="n2" class="form-control" required>
    <select name="operation" id="rst">
        <option value="multiplicar">Multiplicar</option>
        <option value="exponente">Exponente</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Resultado" class="btn btn-primary">

</form>
```

Y en el Archivo2.php escribir:

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_POST["n1"]) || !isset($_POST["n1"]) || !isset($_POST["operation"])){
        echo 'Sin datos enviados';
        die();
    }

    $n1 = $_POST["n1"];
    $n2 = $_POST["n2"];
    $operation = $_POST["operation"];

    if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
        switch ($operation) {
            case 'multiplicar':
                $result = $n1 * $n2;
                echo "La multiplicación de " .$n1. " * " .$n2. " es igual a " .$result;
                break;
            case 'exponente':
                $result = $n1 ** $n2;
                echo "El exponente de " .$n1. " sobre " .$n2. " es igual a " .$result;
                break;
            default:
                $result = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    
    $larrArreglo1 = array();
    $larrArreglo1['n1'] = $n1;
    $larrArreglo1['n2'] = $n2;
    $larrArreglo1['result'] = $result;

    $larrArreglo2 = array();
    $larrArreglo2[] = $n1;
    $larrArreglo2[] = $n2;
    $larrArreglo2[5] = $result;
    
    $larrArreglo3 = array();
    $larrArreglo3['variables'][] = $n1;
    $larrArreglo3['variables'][] = $n2;
    $larrArreglo3['resultado'] = $result;
    
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($larrArreglo1,true) . '</pre>';
    
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($larrArreglo2,true) . '</pre>';
    
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($larrArreglo3,true) . '</pre>';
    
    echo $larrArreglo1['result'];
    
?>
```

En las líneas 3-6 del Archivo2.php estás validando si te han llegado ambas variables.

En las líneas 28-31 del Archivo2.php estás asignando las variables que pides a un arreglo asociativo.

En las líneas 33-36 del Archivo2.php estás asignando las variables que pides a un arreglo con llaves enteras consecutivas desde 0 hasta el tercer elemento que las estas agregando estaticamente.

En las lineas 38 a 41 del Archivo2.php estás asignando las variables que pides a un arreglo de arreglos con llaves asociativas y enteras consecutivas en multinivel.

En las lineas 43, 45 y 47 los estas imprimiendo y en la línea 49 estas imprimiendo el valor del $larrArreglo1 de la llave asociativa 'result'.